# Excel VBA Range object as parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I've written this pretty short VBA macro in Excel which passes 2 Range objects to my own Function. This is the entire code:

```
Sub Cmp()

Dim OneMatch As Boolean
Dim NoMatches As Integer
Dim OneCell, TwoCell As Range

For Each OneCell In Range("X030Pols").Cells
   OneMatch = False: NoMatches = 0

   For Each TwoCell In Range("X206Pols").Cells

           TwoCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = 0

   Next

   For Each TwoCell In Range("X206Pols")
       If TwoCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = "" Then
           TwoCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = PolComp(OneCell, TwoCell)
           If TwoCell.Offset(0, 23).Value > 0 Then
               NoMatches = NoMatches + 1
           End If
       End If
   Next

    If NoMatches = 1 Then
       TwoCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = OneCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
       OneCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = TwoCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
Private Function PolComp(Acell As Range, Bcell As Range) As Integer

If Left(Acell.Offset(0, 1).Value, 4) = Left(Bcell.Offset(0, 1).Value, 4) Then
   PolComp = PolComp + 50
End If

If Acell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Bcell.Offset(0, 6).Value And Acell.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "" Then
   PolComp = PolComp + 50
End If

If Acell.Offset(0, 8).Value = Bcell.Offset(0, 8).Value Then
   PolComp = PolComp + 50
End If

End Function
```

but when I try to run it I get this error:

[image]

So OneCell is defined as a Range, my function uses a Range, but there's a mismatch. The error occurs as it tries to parse my code before it runs anything.

I could work around it but I'm more concerned about understanding what I've done wrong.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  The problem most likely stems from the fact that you're trying to use an unset range object in a for loop.  You Dim the object, but never set it to anything so one of your errors is probably being thrown from an "nothing" object.  What are you looking for in Range("x030Pols")?  Not to mention I don't think you can iterate through a range with another range object.  In my head, it would only execute once since that range would only appear once (if any) in the specified range.

Comment: Also, you're only passing one argument to your function, which is Acell as a range object.

Comment: Try adding `.Cells` to the end of your `For Each` line

Comment: Post your function code pls.

Comment: @StormsEdge Apologies, I tried to simplify the question by only including ONE of the Range objects. I am passing 2 Ranges, a loop within a loop, but this is the code for just one . I have used the For Each format like this many times before. I can refer to the properties of each of the cells within my loop but when I try to pass them to the Function, the error occurs.

Comment: If you can post the rest of the code it would be helpful.  There is a piece missing somewhere and it's difficult to tell what it is elsewhere.  You can definitely use For Each, but my point was that it depends entirely on how you're using the range object.  Is OneCell a global object(Guessing by it's naming convention?)?  .Cells might work like Dan mentioned

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers It's now in the question.

Comment: @Dan, I tried Cells but it didn't work.

Comment: Your function requires two arguments but you are only passing one.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers The full code is now in the question - with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your variable declaration:

```
Dim OneCell, TwoCell As Range
```

This is the same as writing:

```
Dim oneCell as Variant
Dim TwoCell as Range
```

Instead:

```
Dim oneCell as Range
Dim TwoCell as Range
```

Or:

```
Dim OneCell as Range, TwoCell As Range
```

So that VBA doesn't have to guess at your type.

Comment: Thank you very much! I seriously had no idea that Dim worked this way. I've used this syntax on ALL of my VBA projects to date and obviously getting variants all over the place instead of what I actually thought I was getting. I've changed it, tested it and it works, thank you!